# Issue getting the correct image height based on different image types

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview

On my application I've been working on tapping an image and enlarging the image and display the image full size.

Ideally this is what I want to get working:
*(Didn't let me add video here so here's the link to it)*
https://media.giphy.com/media/F7wCO7miVMG6k/source.mp4

However, I'm only able to display images on the correct size if their height is not that tall.
[image: Short height]
[image: Short height full screen]

If I have a square image, or an image too large, the image appears as it follows:
[image: square image] 
[image: square image full]

Here's the code that handles how the image is displayed:

```
var startingFrame: CGRect?
var blackBackgroundView: UIView?
var startingImageView: UIImageView?

func performZoomInForStartingImageView(startingImageView: UIImageView){
    print("starting image view: ", startingImageView.bounds)
    //startingImageView.sizeToFit()

    self.startingImageView = startingImageView
    self.startingImageView?.isHidden = true

    startingFrame = startingImageView.superview?.convert(startingImageView.frame, to: nil)
    print("starting frame: ", startingFrame!)

    let zoomingImageView = UIImageView(frame: startingFrame!)
    //zoomingImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    zoomingImageView.image = startingImageView.image
    print("zoom image view: ", zoomingImageView.bounds )
    zoomingImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    //zoomingImageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin]
    //zoomingImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    zoomingImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleZoomOut)))

    if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

        print("key window frame: ", keyWindow.frame)

        blackBackgroundView = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
        blackBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        blackBackgroundView?.alpha = 0
        keyWindow.addSubview(blackBackgroundView!)
        keyWindow.addSubview(zoomingImageView)


        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.blackBackgroundView?.alpha = 1

            print("keywindow frame width: ", keyWindow.frame.width)
            print("keywindow frame height: ", keyWindow.frame.height)
            print("\nstarting frame height: ", self.startingFrame!.height)
            print("starting frame width: ", self.startingFrame!.width)

            let height = (self.startingFrame!.height / self.startingFrame!.width) * keyWindow.frame.width
            print("height in animate:", height)
            //let height = self.startingFrame!.height * 2

            zoomingImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: height)
            print("zooming image view frame: ", zoomingImageView.frame)

            zoomingImageView.center = keyWindow.center

        }, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

*Note: I added a bunch of print statements to see exactly what was going on with the frame*

I also noticed that my issue happens in the following line:

```
let height = (self.startingFrame!.height / self.startingFrame!.width) * keyWindow.frame.width
```

By using `keyWindow.frame.width` it displays the image with short height correctly, but the other photos height is not correct.

If I change the line to:

```
let height = (self.startingFrame!.height / self.startingFrame!.width) * keyWindow.frame.height
```

it displays the square images correctly, but not the ones with short height.

How can I detect the correct height of the image and display them correctly based on their height?

**Edit:**
*Square image log*
[image: Square image log]

*Wide image log*
[image: Wide image log]

**Edit 2:** *New Logs*

*Square image log*
[image: Square image]

*Wide image log*
[image: Wide image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like adding an `if` condition to check the image is landscape or portrait and set height accordingly,

```
let image = startingImageView.image
let w = image.size.width
let h = image.size.height
print("image width: ", w)
print("image height: ", h)
var height = 0
if (w > h) { //landscape
    height = (self.startingFrame!.height / self.startingFrame!.width) * keyWindow.frame.width
} else { //portrait
    height = (self.startingFrame!.height / self.startingFrame!.width) * keyWindow.frame.height
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The application is portrait only, but the images are still not being displayed correctly based on their height.

Comment: did you tried by checking width to height ratio as above?

Comment: Yes I tried with the code above, but the images are still being displayed incorrectly

Comment: all images or some images? if some which type?

Comment: Square images are displayed wrong. Images that have shorter height are displayed correctly.

Comment: i've made an edit. could you try that and share the log?

Comment: Done. 
The new changes fixed the image issue when it expands. There's just this bug that shows when the image is expanding, first it shows as squeezed and then as it enlarges it shows normal. Then when touching the image again, the final position is a little squeezed before it returns to its original state.

Comment: is that the delay of animation?

Comment: I don't think it would be the delay. The image appears squeezed once I tap it, and then it transitions to full size.